# String to Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: java

I have a string which represents a multidimensional array in the format: [[A, a], [B, b]]

Is there a easy way to convert this string into multidimensional arrays.

Though, for now I am just looking for the above solution the string itself is bit more complicated.

for example in [[A, a], [B, b]]

```
where A could be "This is a sample text, but could be complicated"  

There is a high possibility that the delimiter comma exists in the text (which will be escaped)
```

Thanks, for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have control over the serialized string, I strongly suggest you look into [JSON](http://json.org/fatfree.html). It's an awesome format for things like this. It's lightweight, easy to read, and portable.

For example, from the [link](http://json.org/fatfree.html) (note: the whitespace is not significant--this could all be on one line):

```
[
    [0, -1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1]
]
```

JSON provides a clean and safe mechanism for encoding strings in there, too. Click through for a lot of examples.

Comment: Thanks. I need to look further if it meets my needs. It does look like the way to go. I am not sure yet. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your input format looks like a subset of [JSON](http://json.org/). Any of the Java JSON parsers listed on that page should be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

check this sample:

```
 String[] x = 
  Pattern.compile("ian").split(
    "the darwinian devonian explodian chicken");
for (int i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(i + " \"" + x[i] + "\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used java in a while, but to take a stab answering your question directly:

```
String[] myArray = input.split("(?<!\\),\s*\[");

String[][] myMDArray = new String[myArray.length][];

for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
     myArray[i].replaceAll("(?<!\\)[\[\]]", "");
     myMDArray[i] = myArray[i].split("(?<!\\),");
}
```

Take it for what it's worth.  Like others suggested, there are parsers that will do this with less effort and more flexibility.